# How to tell if an SQL Server is clustered, without interacting with it, preferably via the Registry?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to find out if a given SQL Server instance which its instance name I have, is clustered, without actually connecting it and running queries.

Options:

1. `SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()`: even when it works, it is extremely slow. And again, it doesn't always work (returns empty enumeration??)
2. Registry - I'm sure that information is there, but don't know where...
3. Haven't tried WMI as I'm sure there's an easier solution (e.g. registry...)

Answer (score 1):

TSQL:

```
SELECT 'IsClustered', SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered')
```

Powershell:

```
$s = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemServices -ComputerName $server
if ($s | select PartComponent | where {$_ -like "*ClusSvc*"}) { Write-Output "$server is Clustered" }
else { Write-Output "$server is Not clustered" }
```

Reference http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1182082-1351-1.aspx

There are registry keys that can be checked see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3440/registry-check-pointing-in-a-windows-cluster-to-bring-sql-server-online/ for details.

However TSQL and powershell are much quicker than a remote registry call. If you can make a ADO.NET connection to the instance the TSQL method is the quickest by far.

Comment: Go ADO.NET/ TSQL if you can I just benchmarked it, it's the quickest method. I've added a link to the registry keys that are there for a cluster if that helps, but remote registry calls will be slower.

Comment: This SO post should get you most of the way there with WMI  / C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192544/programmatically-getting-sql-cluster-virtual-name

Comment: The issue with TSQL is that I've got to start fiddling with connecting to the SQL Server (connection strings, logging in, usernames, passwords, etc...). I already have the instances names & versions from the Registry (best method by far - easiest and fastest in run-time).